# How do I get a list of all unique PHP GETs to my site from the logs?

Tags: php, macos, logging, grep

In my log I have many lines that look like this:

```
mysitename.net 1.23.45.67 - - [10/Mar/2017:20:28:38 +0000] "GET /foldername/special/somefile.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2012
```

Is there any way to grep all the unique PHP GETs into a file, so I have a list of any/all files on the server that were accessed?

I tried:

```
grep -i "GET [\w]+.php" mylogfile.txt > results.txt
```

but it does not return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

For grep, i would do it like this:

```
$ a=$'mysitename.net 1.23.45.67 - - [10/Mar/2017:20:28:38 +0000] "GET /foldername/special/somefile.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2012' 
$ grep -Eo 'GET.*php' <<<"$a"
GET /foldername/special/somefile.php
```

Personally, especially in mac, i would go for perl -pe oneliner, since works the same in all platforms, using regex group matching with backreference.

In bellow example , the whole input string is divided in groups using parenthesis. Working with perl substitution (identical to sed) we can force perl to return to us only the third input group:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.*)(GET )(.*.php)(.*)/\3/g' <<<"$a" #if you want to include also the GET in your results then modify last part like .../\2\3/g'
/foldername/special/somefile.php
```

Comment: @user7692690 Grep solution added